# How C#/Java stores 2D array, it's different with C++?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, memory

As I know, C++ stores array by putting 2D array values on a block of memory (continuous virtual memory?), which are fast for accessing value by index.

I came out this question after reading this, "using nested array to store 2D grid is efficient in C/C++, but in Java or other memory-managed languages, doing that will actually give you an array of rows where each element is a reference to the array of columns, which may not be as memory-friendly as you'd like".

Does "a reference to the array of columns" mean they actually be stored in many tiny blocks on memory?

**Update**

Sorry my question should be "If Java store 2D array on many tiny blocks, how is this easy for 'memory-management'"?

Comment: Whoever wrote that is probably thinking of an `int[][]` which is indeed an array of arrays. That's all there is in Java, but in C# there's *also* an `int[,]` which is a rectangular array - a single chunk of contiguous memory.

Comment: Does "a reference to the array of columns" mean they actually be stored in many tiny blocks on memory? -- **Yes** (in Java), But what is the pro and cons here? - please refine your question, as it stands it is just asking for opinions without a particular direction, which is not suitable for SO.

Comment: No it means, that there are no "real" 2d arrays in Java (and maybe C# as well). Java instead can has arrays of arrays, where each index of array 1 (the rows) is an array itself (the columns). That also means, that the columns can be jagged.

Comment: You may as well add every language that has either of these features. Really every language.

Comment: @Tom No, Jon Skeet's right (as usual), you can definitely create a true 2d array in C#.

Comment: @PCLuddite I wonder what the meaning of "maybe" is ... ;P. I don't know how C# works, thats why I've added that word.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I don't know Java actually can have jagged array. I guess it is the reason for putting rows on different blocks

Comment: "how is this easy for 'memory-management'?" it is and it isn't. It't often easier to acquire a lot of little blocks of memory than one big one. If the memory manager needs 100 bytes, that's chump change. Those memory runs are probably just lying around in between the seat cushions. 100,000,000 bytes might take a bit of looking, depending on how fragmented the memory is. But 1 big block of memory is easy to put away. One call, all done. A million small blocks... Might take a while.

Answer (score 1):

In an MxN matrix, it has M references for N arrays. And that is the reason that in C you must tell the second dimension when you want to pass an array as a function argument, and in Java you dont have to.